# vba vlookup to populate a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form with a combo box and a submit button which enters the selections made by users from the drop down onto a worksheet on the first empty row.The combo box vba works fine. However, for example if the combo box choice  is entered in cell C2 (because the first empty row is 2 and C isalways the column where the combo box enters the result) I want in column D to have a vlookup formula in VBA which, based on what it is in column C to autofill AUTOMATICALLY AT THE SAME TIME column D. Like when you drag down a vlookup formula in column D based on the values in column C.

This is what I've got so far but it does not work. The vlookup part doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

```
 With Sheets("TasksData").Range("D2", Sheets("TasksData").Cells      
  (Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & .Row & ",'ValidationTables'!$L:$M,2,FALSE)"
    .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
  End With
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `With` statement looks a little off to me.  Were you getting an error?

Try this instead:

```
Dim lastRow
With Sheets("TasksData")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3))
        .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1= "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'ValidationTables'!C12:C13,2,FALSE)"
        .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: `.Range(.Rows.Count, "D")` would need to either be `.Range("D" & .Rows.Count)` or `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D")`

Comment: I think what you are after is actually `With .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))` - i.e. select all the range of cells in column C so that the later `Offset(, 1)` is pointing to column D

Comment: And, of course, `"=VLOOKUP(C" & .Row & ", ...` could be simplified to be `"=VLOOKUP(C2, ...` because the first row of the range being used as the object of the `With` block (which is therefore what is returned by `.Row`) will be 2.

Comment: (I think I need to ask Commissioner Gordon whether I can borrow the Bat Signal !)

Comment: @YowE3K man, I've been off my game recently. Do you happen to fit in a child size yellow and red spandex suit, with an "R" on it? ...wait why would I know anything about that....

Comment: @YowE3K (I'm on mobile so can't tell, did you edit my post to fix with your comments? It looks like you did, so thank you!!!)

Comment: Yes, I updated your answer to reflect my comments once the OP confirmed that they fixed the problem.  I figured you (or someone who looks a lot like you) was out fighting crime and therefore couldn't be handling minor typos (etc) like this.

Comment: @YowE3K I'm a business man! ...and have been busy fighting business. ...anyways thanks for your help. I need to take this weekend to get my mind back from the Riddl...I mean thinking of business....

Comment: @YowE3K sorry, I've just realised a glitch in the code above. My worksheet has headers on row 1 and the vba above overwrites the first row with "#N/A". Is there a way for never changing row 1? thanks

Comment: or perhaps something to say to find the first blank row? i'm a little stuck

Comment: @thankseveryone it overwrites row 1? Are you sure the code you posted is doing it? It shouldn't since we start at row 2. Use `F8` to step through your code and let us know where it's actually overwriting the first row.

Comment: @thankseveryone The only possible way this section of the code would overwrite row 1 is if column C was completely empty, or just had something in C1.  (It would then be writing to `D2:D1`.)  In your question you say that the placing of data into column C is working - are you sure that it is?  Or is the data being placed into column C **after** the code we fixed?

Comment: thanks both for your reply. Cell C1 contains the header ''Name" and cell D1 contains the header "Price". cell C1 "Name" always stays on my worksheet but D1 becomes #N/A. I've just added a screenshot of what the result is eg screenshot picture of what it looks like. Can you spot anything to fix the problem? thanks

Comment: basically the first row (row 1) always has the headers which should never change or disappear. Does it make sense?

Comment: @thankseveryone - See the edit. I added a short `lastRow` line, to help determine the last row. Now, are you *positive* it's this part of the code that's overwriting data in the first row?

Comment: @thankseveryone - step through your code with `F8` and try to isolate when it's writing data to the first row. Also if you could post more code it'd help us.  ... I'm not sure if that'd be a new question though as what I posted *should* answer the `With` statement question ...unless it still isn't working